# How to join urls in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Python has a really hand functionality with [urllib.parse.urljoin](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin) in which it handles joining urls, examples:

merging urls:

```
>>> urllib.parse.urljoin('https://something.a.com/api/v3/', 'some/end/point')
'https://something.a.com/api/v3/some/end/point'
```

I am looking at the [QT documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html) and I cannot find anything like this in there. How do people deal with this two situations? I guess I could manually merge things with QStrings, but that seems a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`QUrl::resolved`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#resolved) serves that purpose. It merges the relative URL passed as an argument with the base url given by the instance you call it on:

```
auto full = base.resolved(relative);
```

Comment: @Mac Well, you resolve multiple pieces into a final thing. Perhaps it's terminology from the relevant rfc?